# How to convert from Date(10-Oct-2014 00:00:00) to String in Java

Tags: java

I want to compare two date values in Java

```
Date date1=10-Oct-2014 00:00:00(value fetched from DB)
Date date2=10-Oct-2014 00:00:00(value fetched from DB)
```

How do I convert this date values into String format in Java so that I cant compare them or else is there any way I can compare these dates.

Comment: Why you do not use the `compareTo` method from `java.util.Date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would compare the long values of both dates like this:
if the dates are nullable dont forgett the nullcheck!

```
if (date1!=null && date2 != null){
   if (date1.getTime() == date2.getTime()){
      System.out.println("Dates are equal");
   }
}
```

There is no need to cast the Date objects to String objects.

Comment: why not `date1.equals(date2))`?

Comment: This isn't going to work as you are comparing the reference rather than the actual date object.

Comment: never ever! getTime returns long not Long. Using == is absolutly ok

Answer (score 0):

You should be using compareTo method for less than or equal or greater than. You could do it like:

```
 int dateComparison = date1.compareTo(date2);
 if (dateComparison  == 0) {
     //both dates are equal
 } else if (dateComparison  < 0) {
     //date2 is greater
 } else {
     //date1 is greater
 }
```

if you are just looking for equality, you could use equals method on date like below:

```
 if (date1.equals(date2)) {
    //two dates are equal
 }
```

Comment: instead of `date1.compareTo(date) < 0` you can use `date1.before(date2)`.